# Extract a string of text before name and surname in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I'm in a bit of a predicament, since i have a large amount of data to go through and i need to isolate a string of text.

Example, column A :

A1 - Mister John Doe

A2 - His Excellency Mister Mark Smith

My goal is to isolate the terms coming before the name and surname. Ex : B1 - Mister ; B2 His Excellency Mister

How can this be done with a formula?

Thanks in advance for your kind help !

Comment: How is Excel supposed to know what is a name and what is not?

Comment: Only idea I have is to have 5 helper columns and then use find() to locate the spaces and then use mid() and right() to find the last two items which could be assumed to be name and surname, BUT if they have two names and a surname ....

Comment: Perhaps a helper column that finds title words like "Mister", "Miss", "Doctor", or etc, then use mid to delete everything before the title and the title itself? Then you'll at least have the names.

Comment: there is only one name and one surname if that helps. I was thinking maybe a formula that "grabs" everything before the two spaces (one before name and one before surname). if that can work obviously...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
 =IFERROR(REPLACE(A1, FIND("|", SUBSTITUTE(A1, " ", "|", LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1, " ", ""))-1)), LEN(A1), ""), "")
```

[image]